# How to reuse python variable which was assigned to a s3 return object from AWS

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, dataframe, amazon-s3, boto3

I need to reuse a python variable which stores the object returned from a s3 get_object call. Below is my code

```
def check_csv_format(s3_object):
    try:
       pd.read_csv(obj['Body'], header=None)
    except Exception as e:
       raise Exception(e)

obj = s3.get_object(bucket, key)
check_csv_format(obj)
df = pd.read_csv(obj['Body'])
```

But when i run this code, it gives below error.

```
pandas.errors.EmptyDataError: No columns to parse from file
```

I tried to use python deepcopy to keep a copy of that object. But it didn't work. Suggest a solution pls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `obj['Body']` element in the returned dict is a [StreamingBody](https://botocore.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/response.html#botocore.response.StreamingBody). It doesn't support seek or re-streaming. If you call `read()` on it passing no parameters then you read all of the data. So, if you call `read()` a 2nd time, you will get no more bytes.

Why don't you simply save the streamed object like this:

```
csv_content = obj['Body'].read().decode('utf-8')
```

Then you can pass `csv_content` to Pandas as needed.